# Iterate through dict from smallest to largest key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict like so:

```
my_dict = {'hello':'2' , 'foo':'1' , 'foobar':'3'}
```

I don't want to modify the dict in any way, I just want to iterate through it from the smallest sized key to the largest sized key like so...

```
for key in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[key])

# Results
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Comment: Do you mean sorted by length of the key? Then `for key in sorted(my_dict, key=len):`

Comment: I'm not trying to sort by value, I'm trying to sort by length of key, please reopen the question.

Comment: @gnibbler Thank you gnibbler that works, I'd accept your answer but this question has been marked as a duplicate for no reason...

Comment: @Ogen In that case simply replace `dict1.get` with `len` in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3177911/846892 Ah! gnibbler already posted that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary What if another user wants to achieve what I'm doing. It would be more convenient for them to be able to just search this question rather than searching a related question then connecting the dots.

Comment: @Ogen Instead of ranting here learn to use Google: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+sort+a+dictionary+by+value+in+python

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This particular question hasn't been asked on stack overflow, only variants of it. You'd know that if you spent some time looking instead of blindly marking it as a duplicate

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You should probably put that link as the duplicate instead of the sorting by value one that's currently there.

Comment: @Ogen I've re-opened and closed the question again as the more suitable duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following snippet

```
for key in sorted(my_dict, key = len):
    print my_dict[key]
1
2
3
```

The `len` above is the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function, which means all the entries in my_dict.keys() will be sorted by length, and then their values will be printed

Comment: `.keys()` call is unnecessary, and will create a list in Python 2.